# Android failing to send large json string through Http Post

Tags: android, image, upload, base64

I am trying to send an image as a base64 to a php based web service. The image that  I am sending is around 500 kb . I am first compressing the image and then converting the image into base64 string. But the image is not being sent. If i try it through Fiddler, I am successful in sending the image. Is there anyway to increase the http post request call of android? I am using the following libraries: DefaultHttpClient and HttpPost.

Answer (score 0):

In my case , adding UTF-8 solved my problem

```
StringEntity se;
se = new StringEntity(json.toString(),"UTF-8");
            httppostreq.setEntity(se);
            response = client.execute(httppostreq);
```